# Raring doesn't boot after EFI install

Tags: boot, 13.04, 64-bit, uefi

I'm trying to install 13.04 64-bit server on an AMD Fusion based System (C60M1-i). Installation medium is a USB Stick created with unetbootin (or, better: several of them already).

Ubuntu Live boots well, only after installing Server/Desktop I get a black screen

> Missing operation system.
>
> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

I already
- tried diverse downloaded Images (including Raring Desktop)
- partioned the disk using GPT
- ran boot-repair

boot-repair log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5745089

to no avail.

But the EFI doesn't recognise the bootdisk (Sandisk SSD) as bootable (doesn't show as UEFI: Sandisk P4... in the Mainboard Setup).

I have no control over secure boot (Mainboard doesn't offer an option).

How could i get this system booting? I actually wouldn't care booting Legacy (BIOS) in the end...

Thank you for any advice.

Best
Constantin

Edit #3: It seems that the problem is, that `efibootmgr` cannot write the boot-entry to the NVRAM (seems like a bug with some or many EFI boards, at least it is mentioned with different ASUS models on the web. Some folks mention a bug in efibootmgr as well ... will try to figure out). I for now sort of worked around it by placing a copy of `grubx64.efi` to the root of the EFI partition and then from the mainboard setup call **'Start EFI Shell from filesystem'**. E voilá - there's grub and I can boot. Will need to find a complete solution, still.

Edit #4:
Might have to do with this: [Sony VAIO with Insyde H2O EFI bios will not boot into GRUB EFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it a clean Ubuntu install or a dual boot setup?

Comment: Clean. Freshly partitioned SSD. (GPT)

Comment: It sounds like you are not using EFI, but are booting in BIOS mode, and you didn't create a bios_grub partition so installing grub failed.  You would have gotten an error message to that effect when installing.  Try again and make a 1 MiB bios_grub type partition.

Comment: No. It was and is installed in EFI Mode. See 'Edit #3'.

Comment: It's most likely related to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286462/13-04-not-leaving-any-efibootmgr-entries

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `bcfg` from an EFI version 2 shell:

1. Download an EFI version 2 shell. [Here is a link](https://edk2.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/edk2/trunk/edk2/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi) to a semi-official binary. If that binary  hangs, try [this one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17629062/Shell2.zip), but note that you'll need to unzip the shell program from the zip file. (The second program should work on older computers, which the first one doesn't support.)
2. Create a USB flash drive with a FAT partition.
3. Copy the EFI shell to the USB flash drive as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the flash drive. For instance, if you mount the flash drive at `/media/flash`, the file should be `/media/flash/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.
4. Reboot and tell your computer to boot from the USB flash drive.
5. In the EFI shell, type `bcfg boot dump -v` to see the current boot entries. Note the highest number in the existing boot entries.
6. Add a new boot entry using `bcfg boot add 3 fs0:\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi "Ubuntu"`, changing `3` to a value higher than any in the list you got from the previous step.
7. Type `bcfg boot mv 3 0` to make GRUB the default boot entry. (Change `3` to the number you used in the previous step.)

When you reboot normally, the computer should boot into GRUB by default.